# Concatenation of HTML string using PHP or Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, string, concatenation

I need to do a HTML string concat (using PHP or Javascript) and I don't know how to do it.

What I'd like

```
<src="http://maps.google"+$city+"rest_of_the_link">
```

(I've already tried the previous code but it doesn't do the trick)

Comment: HTML is not a programming language. What on earth is `$city` supposed to be?

Comment: @BoltClock $city is a variable containing the name of a city.

Comment: HTML does not have variables.

Comment: @Bruno No it's not. Unless it's in a language other than HTML... Javascript? PHP?

Comment: @Paul Pro That's why I'm looking for a way to do this with PHP or Javascript.

Comment: As I implied in my response to your comment on my answer — how you go about this depends on other factors (such as where you get the data from).

Comment: Now your edit makes things clearer. We're not supposed to infer these things from reading a question that basically makes no sense otherwise.

Comment: Downvotes seem totally unnecessary. OP doesn't have to know what language the solution will come from.

Comment: @Bruno What language is `$city`?

Comment: @Quentin The data comes from the name of the file (I get it using PHP with $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and basename).

Comment: The question needs more detail. If you don't know what language should be used to solve a problem then you should be zooming out and describing the problem in general not trying to solve a specific syntax problem like string concatenation.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is <src="http://maps.google<?php echo $city ?>rest_of_the_link">, but that will only work in an a *.php file.

Comment: @Bruno Then you can concatenate with the `.` operator like: `'some string '.$city.' some other string';` In php you can also put a variable directly in a double quoted string and it will be parsed, like `"some string $city some other string";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using PHP:

```
<src="http://maps.google<?=$city?>rest_of_the_link">
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't. HTML doesn't have strings … or variables. It is a markup language, not a programming language.

You can generate HTML from another language (which could be a program that is executed automatically by a webserver to generate the content for a URL), and you can use DOM APIs (again from another language) to manipulate a DOM generated from an HTML document.

Comment: There isn't a way (PHP, Javascript) to do this ?

Comment: @Bruno PHP and Javascript are ways to do this.  But that's not your question, your question is how to do it in *HTML*.

Comment: Both PHP and JavaScript qualify as "another language" and could be used to generate HTML and to manipulate a DOM generated from an HTML document. Which language and technique you use would depend on a number of factors (such as where you are getting the data from, how your document is stored, and the context surrounding your problem).

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do that with HTML alone. HTML is not a programming language, it's a markup language (hence the HyperText **Markup** Language), for that reason, no variables (or control structures, or anything of that sort) is in it.

What you need to do, is to supply yourself with a different language to help **generate** the HTML.

For example, in PHP you'd do something like so:

```
<?php
    $city = "London"; //Set the variable
    echo "<src=\"http://maps.google".$city."rest_of_the_link\">"; //Echo result concatenating $city inside.
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is templating.

You can load the HTML as a template, and then plant values in specific locations. If you load it from the server side you can use django templates (I use django and my backend is in python), and if you're doing it from the client size, through javascript, you can use jquery templates or the jqote plugin for jquery which is apparently faster than the native jquery solution.

For example, If you're using django, your html would look something like this:

```
<src="http://maps.google{{city}}rest_of_the_link">
```

And when you load it using the server, you pass a dictionary object that has a value for the key 'city'.

I'm not sure what is the best method for php templates, but this is something you can probably find easily when you know what you're searching for.

Answer (score 0):

You need a serverside language like PHP or ASP to do this. You can also build the url dynamically using Javascript (or a combination of one of these options) but your question does not make clear where the value of the variable must come from.

Answer (score 0):

Html is not a programming language, you can achieve it by using JavaScript DOM or JQuery.
Just access the the anchor object, manipulate and assign its attribute.

Answer (score 0):

```
<src="maps.google<?php echo $city ?>rest_of_the_link">
```

Assuming you're using PHP and this is in a .php file.